# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest crashes on slow network

Tags: ios, crash, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I am using `NSURLConnection` `sendSynchronousRequest` to download data and it crashes at that statement.

Code is as follows:

```
_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
_urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.url];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

if(![self isCancelled])
 {
       _receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_urlRequest returningResponse:&response
                                                                    error:&error];
 }
 _error = error;
```

**Reason:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType URL]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1cd2eaf0'

**When i backtrace I get this:**

> - thread #7: tid = 0x240f, 0x397a1350 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue =
>     'com.apple.root.default-priority', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
>     frame #0: 0x397a1350 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
>     frame #1: 0x39718122 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 58
>     frame #2: 0x39754972 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 94
>     frame #3: 0x38cf2d4e libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 74
>     frame #4: 0x38cefff8 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate() + 24
>     frame #5: 0x392a3a76 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 146
>     frame #6: 0x38cf007a libc++abi.dylib`safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 78
>     frame #7: 0x38cf0114 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 20
>     frame #8: 0x38cf1512 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 122
>     frame #9: 0x392a39be libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 94
>     frame #10: 0x31626e06 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 170
>     frame #11: 0x31625530 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 392
>     frame #12: 0x3157cf68 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
>     frame #13: 0x31f5e21e Foundation`+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 334   * frame #14:
>     0x001268d0 Rangeela`-[RGFeedOperation main](self=0x1cd35180,
>     _cmd=0x370c3394) + 3284 at RGFeedOperation.m:90
>     frame #15: 0x31eb05c0 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal start] + 840
>     frame #16: 0x31f28be2 Foundation`__block_global_6 + 102
>     frame #17: 0x396bb11e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
>     frame #18: 0x396c9258 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 260
>     frame #19: 0x396c93b8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
>     frame #20: 0x396efa10 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 360

Can someone please help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: Can you post the code where you are creating the URL?

Comment: Updated my ques. urlString is a basic URL string

Comment: Well, I just created a sample project with same code but different URL and it worked well. So I guess there is either something wrong with your URL creation or maybe some object is getting released, which is most probably could be the _urlRequest. Make sure you are doing memory management properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message,  you're trying to send a method to an object that doesn't have that method.  Go through all your declarations and make sure you're sending the right type of objects to the routine that crashes.  Did you send a NSURL where a NSURLResponse or NSURLConnection is wanted?

Comment: What is the difference between:

_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

and 

_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: But I don't think encoding is your problem. That would result in an unopened web page, not a crash.